# Multiple functionalities inside NodeJS request

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a single script in Node to process all my requests and do something according to each and send certain data.

What I want to achieve is to have a server running on `localhost:3000` but make multiple requests over there:

```
localhost:3000/modules -> GET
localhost:3000/modules/:id -> GET
localhost:3000/modules/add?params -> POST
localhost/reports/:id -> GET
locahost/qav/analytics/first -> GET
locahost/qav/analytics/last -> GET
locahost/qav/analytics/:id -> GET
```

How can I make a request to localhost:3000 and detect if there is a different URL location?

I tried using this approach:

```
res.writeHead( 301, { "Location" : "/modules" } );
```

and process this in all the requests:

```
switch( req.url )
{
  case "/modules":
      ...
  break;
}
```

But when I try to enter in the browser to a get method: `localhost:3000/modules` it is supposed to return me a text that says "in modules" but it timeouts or sometimes tries to open a file...

How do I achieve to create a single NodeJS script to check if I made a request to /modules, /modules/:id, etc. and/or get the params of each?

Comment: Post enough of your code so we can see how it all works.  You are sending back a header with a moved permanently response. Where are you returning: "in modules" ?  Also it seems to me that what you want is to install express or another framework that is meant to handle all these sorts of things.  If you are trying to create your own, look at the source.

Comment: I tried to search for different keywords after your comment with no success. Finally found something called Express Routing, which seems to be what I want. The next time would be helpful to give advice on "maybe you are looking for this" instead of saying "install express". Had no idea it was called "Express routing".

Answer (score 1):

What I needed is something called `"Routing"`. Succesfully achieved this by using `Express Basic Routing`.

Creating express routes by each method within the given path:

```
app.METHOD( "PATH", func );
```

where "PATH" can be "/modules" and METHOD { get, post, put, delete, etc }